# How to bind lists in javaFX?

Tags: list, javafx, bind

I'm trying to implement a **MVP pattern**. My Model contains **several lists**, and when a list is modify, I want to inform my Presenter. To do so, I think about using `bindlist`, but i'm new to javaFX, and I don't really know how to do it.

Is my vision to solve my problem correct , and how simply implement bind list ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple solutions. E.g. if you have an [ObservableList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html), you can simply set it as the model for the control if you like (e.g. [ListView.setItems](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html#setItems-javafx.collections.ObservableList-)).

Otherwise have a look at the bindContent methods of the [Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html) utility class.

Comment: Can you develop your explanation on Observation List, if I put an observation list in my model class, how to inform my controller or make the link ?

Comment: @EvansBelloeil which solution are you talking about? The one where you share the same list object or the one where you bind the content? Both can work with ObservableLists...

Comment: The solution where you share your content, because my presenter can also modify my model.

Comment: @EvansBelloeil If both the control and the model share the same ObservableList object then by definition both have the same content. If you need something else, please describe it.

Comment: With your help I found this doc : https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/collections/jfxpub-collections.htm ,thanks.